# Group Policy Object Path

Tags: group-policy

I was wondering if there is a way to copy the group policy path. For example:

Deafault Domain Policy> Computer Configuration> Windows Settings> Security Settings> Account Policies> Kerberos Policy> 'Maximum lifetime for service ticket'

Now above is the path to go to 'Maximum lifetime for service ticket'

Acutally i need it for logging the changes, So that i know what i have changed in the policy.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the tool 'Advanced Group Policy Management' that can be dowloaded as part of Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack (MDOP). You can track changes to  GPO's with this tool and can even rollback changes if neended.

The downside is how to get it. It is available for Software Assurance Customers only. It can also be downloaded if you have technet subscription or MSDN, but for testing purposes only.

If your can not download this. You can download a vbscript collection from microsoft at:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14536

Scripts you might like:

- GetReportsForAllGPOs.wsf
- BackupAllGPOs.wsf